# RStudio Automatically Running Something Upon Starting it

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm having a very unusual problem with RStudio today. When I launch the application it automatically seems to run something.

The reason I say 'something' is because all of the panels are blank, yet my computer starts running an rsession node at 99 %CPU capacity, and the console, although blank, has the little red stop sigh on the top right side of the box, indicating it is running something...

Has anybody ever run though this issue? I've tried to force quit, restart the computer & interrupt the session but nothing in sight.

FYI: R version 3.6.1
RSTUDIO verison 1.2.5019

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling RStudio?

Comment: Does it also happen when you open R outside of RStudio? Maybe try `RGui.exe` on Windows or `R.app` on MacOS. If the issue is the same there, then just reinstall R instead of RStudio.

Comment: Hi,pleas check globle environment is empty. press ```altr + ctrl + delete``` and stop rstudio. hope this will help.